# minimum distance function between strings

Tags: r

completely edited, big thanks shayaa for the advice!

out of sentences in a matrix (read in from csv), there shall be words detected which are stored in lists (read in from txt).

```
sentences_list <- matrix(c(
    "this screen is great", 
    "this camera is not bad", 
    "everything good but the camera is awesome",
    "everything bad but the camera is awesome",
    "battery is ok but the camera is awesome"), ncol = 1)

word_list_one <-list("screen", "camera", "battery")
word_list_two <-list("good", "great", "awesome")
word_list_three <-list("bad", "awful", "poor")
word_list_four <-list("not", "don't", "neither")

    one <- apply(sentences_list, 2, function(x) {
        str_detect(x, paste(word_list_one, sep = '|', collapse = '|'))
    })

    two <- apply(sentences_list, 2, function(x) {
      str_detect(x, paste(word_list_two, sep = '|', collapse = '|'))
    })

    three <- apply(sentences_list, 2, function(x) {
      str_detect(x, paste(word_list_three, sep = '|', collapse = '|'))
    })

    four <- apply(sentences_list, 2, function(x) {
      str_detect(x, paste(word_list_four, sep = '|', collapse = '|'))
    })
```

The following code can be taken for reviewing which words were matched. (the results are stored instead of directly displayed, because the number of results is counted in a certain way in the aftermath)

```
row=5

print(sentences_list[row])
c(str_extract(sentences_list[row], paste(word_list_one, sep = '|', collapse = '|')))
c(str_extract(sentences_list[row], paste(word_list_two, sep = '|', collapse = '|')))
c(str_extract(sentences_list[row], paste(word_list_three, sep = '|', collapse = '|')))
c(str_extract(sentences_list[row], paste(word_list_four, sep = '|', collapse = '|')))
```

For `row=1` and `row=2` everything works as it should, but not for the following. This is because only the first match in a sentence from the `word_list_x` is returned. What I would rather like the code to do, is giving back the word for a `word_list_x` which is the closest in distance to the word found in another `word_list_`.

so for `row=3`in `sentences_list` the result for the `word_list_two = "good"`, because it is found first. What should be the result is `word_list_two = "awesome"` because in the sentence of `row=3` it stands closer to the result found in `word_list_one = "camera"`.

as for `row=4`in `sentences_list` the result for the `word_list_three = "bad"` and `word_list_two = "awesome"`. Because the result from `word_list_two`is closer in distance to the result found in `word_list_one = "camera"` only the result from `word_list_two = "awesome"` should be returned leaving `word_list_three = " "`blank.

as for `row=5`in `sentences_list` the result for the `word_list_one = "battery"`, because it is found first. What should be the result is `word_list_one = "camera"` because in the sentence of `row=5` it stands closer to the result found in `word_list_two= "great"`.

Obviously, as a novice, I am completely overstrained with the scale of that project and I am very grateful for any help you can provide,thank you very much!

Comment: Just fyi, this is not a reproducible example. I can not run your code start to finish and reproduce your results. I don't have your `df` with lists of words. By and large, a `data.frame` is not the best repository for your words. A vector is. For many vectors of words you would want to use a list. Perhaps you can edit this question again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise, I appreciate! I am still very new to R and also stackoverflow. I will try to improve the question in terms of the reproducible example in a moment. I am not perfectly familiar with all the repositories but I managed to provide lists of the words I want to find in the text. As for the text, I do not know how to read in my csv file with multiple sentences for each element into somethin other than a data.frame or a matrix. Would a matrix do?

Comment: Hi @dennis, I have a quick question, what if the last element of `sentences_list` were for instance "battery is good but the camera is awesome", what would be the result? In that case, you could detect distances from two different words from `word_list_one`: "camera" and "battery", and both would have a word from `word_list_two` at the same distance: "good" and "awesome".

Comment: Sorry for the Late answer, got the Mail just now.. Whenever two Words from word_list_one are found and there also are two words from word_list_two/ three  and of the distance between them is totaly equal, than it should simply be counted as it occurs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I came up with. I have taken an approach in which the result is a `data.frame` where the first column contains one word from the first list, and the other columns "two", "three" and "four" contains the nearest word of each of these lists to the word in the first column. First, two functions to calculate minimum distances:

```
getMinimumDistanceWord <- function(text, word, wordList){
  min <- " "
  minDist <- 1000
  for (w in wordList){
    d <- distanceBetweenWords(text, word, w)
    if (d != 0 && d < minDist){
      min <- w
      minDist <- d
    }
  }
  return (list(min, minDist))
}


distanceBetweenWords <- function(text, word1, word2){
  x <- strsplit(text, " ")[[1]]
  dist <- abs(grep(word1, x) - grep(word2, x))
  if (length(dist) == 0) return (0)
  else return (dist)
}
```

Now, iterate over the sentence list and calculate the minimum distances:

```
res <- data.frame(one = character(), two = character(), three = character(), four = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
i <- 1
for(elem in sentences_list){
  base.word.list <- unlist(str_extract_all(elem, paste(word_list_one, sep = '|', collapse = '|')))
  res[i, 1] <- base.word.list[1]
  res[i, 2] <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, base.word.list[1], word_list_two)[1]
  res[i, 3] <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, base.word.list[1], word_list_three)[1]
  res[i, 4] <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, base.word.list[1], word_list_four)[1]
  if (length(base.word.list) != 1){
    currentDistance2 <- as.numeric(unlist(getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, base.word.list[1], word_list_two))[2])
    currentDistance3 <- as.numeric(unlist(getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, base.word.list[1], word_list_three))[2])
    currentDistance4 <- as.numeric(unlist(getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, base.word.list[1], word_list_four))[2])
    for(currentWord in base.word.list){
      if (getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_two)[2] < as.numeric(currentDistance2)){
        currentDistance2 <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_two)[2]
        res[i, 1] <- currentWord
        res[i, 2] <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_two)[1]
      }
      if (getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_three)[2] < as.numeric(currentDistance3)){
        currentDistance3 <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_three)[2]
        res[i, 1] <- currentWord
        res[i, 3] <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_three)[1]
      }
      if (getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_four)[2] < as.numeric(currentDistance4)){
        currentDistance4 <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_four)[2]
        res[i, 1] <- currentWord
        res[i, 4] <- getMinimumDistanceWord(elem, currentWord, word_list_four)[1]
      }
    }
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

The result data.frame would be this:

```
     one     two three four
1 screen   great           
2 camera           bad  not
3 camera awesome           
4 camera awesome   bad     
5 camera awesome
```

For instance, the first row says that the nearest word to the word "screen" (in the list one) is "great" (of the list two), and that there are not other nearest words from lists "three" and "four". Similarly, the fifth row says that the nearest word (in the fifth sentence) to "camera" is "awesome". The second row says that, in the second sentence, there is one "nearest" word to "camera" in the third list ("bad"), and there is also another nearest word ("not") from the fourth list.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this

I edited your data so it runs

```
df <- c("second" , "word1", "word2", "word3", 
          "word4","first",  "word1", "word2", "third")
one <- "third"
two <- c("second", "third")
```

Match each vector

```
match1 <-match(one, df)
match2 <- match(two, df)
match3 <- match("first",df)
```

Determine the position of the matched vector which is closest to the word you are looking for, in this case, the word "first"

```
closest <- which.min(abs(match2 - match3))
```

Now check your answers

```
df[match1]
[1] "third"

df[match2[closest]]
[1] "third"
```

Edited to answer your edits:

I would do as follows

```
library(stringr)
sentences_list <- list("this screen is great", 
  "this camera is not bad", 
  "everything good but the camera is awesome",
  "everything bad but the camera is awesome",
  "battery is ok but the camera is awesome")

word_list_one <- c("screen", "camera", "battery")
word_list_two <- c("good", "great", "awesome")
word_list_three <- c("bad", "awful", "poor")
word_list_four <- c("not", "don't", "neither")

l <- lapply(sentences_list, str_match_all, word_list_one)
```

The `str_match_all` function will return a list of 5 lists each with three elements. The first list in `l` returns the matches from the first word list as well as the matched word.

This is the same as saving them as you did in your original matrix and using

```
apply(sentences_list,1, str_match_all, word_list_one)
```

You should be able to complete the example with the original answer I provided.

Comment: Thank you for very much for your Answer! I get it working for the part you recently edited. For the following implementation of the original answer you provided, I don't really get the code working. I now get the `match1` etc as `NA NA NA NA NA`. For both options you provided, so the `apply` and the `lapply` In addition to that, I don't really get the concept of what you did with match and closest.